# How do I add a new item or object to an existing object?

Tags: templating, plugin-imager, twigextension

I'm using the [Imager](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft) plugin and Craft for image compression.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
{% set imagerConfig = { jpegQuality: 80, pngCompressionLevel: 4 } %}
```

In another part of my code, I want to do something like:

```
 {% set largeLogo = craft.imager.transformImage((logo.getUrl('LargeLogo')), imagerConfig) %}
```

Where I want to do something like this to `imagerConfig` above:

```
{% set width = {width: 1000} %} or {%set widthRatio = {width: 1000, ratio: 4/2} %}
imagerConfig.Add(width) //what's the proper syntax for adding an item or even another object(like widthRatio above) to imagerConfig here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Twig curly brace `{}`, key/value pair syntax like you've got `imagerConfig` set to, you're using the Twig [hash](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#literals) literal.

In Twig, if you want to add to an array or hash after it has already been created, you can use the [merge](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html#merge) filter.

Something like this should do what you're looking for:

```
{% set imagerConfig = { jpegQuality: 80, pngCompressionLevel: 4 } %}

{% set width = { width: 1000 } %}

{% set imagerConfig = imagerConfig|merge(width) %}

{% set largeLogo = craft.imager.transformImage((logo.getUrl('LargeLogo')), imagerConfig) %}
```